# PDF is not being opened in Chrome started by Selenium

Tags: java, google-chrome, pdf, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium and ChromeDriver 2.43.1 with the latest Chrome (Version 42.0.2311.135 at the time the quetion was asked). My web application generates a PDF. It is being sent with the correct MIME type and it also correctly opens in the Chrome PDF viewer. However when I try to open the PDF using Selenium in Chrome that is started by the WebDriver, it gets downloaded.

I believe it might be some settings that Selenium or WebDriver use to start Chrome.

I've tried [settings a few switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/), but nothing worked yet. My code:

```java
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
// Add ChromeDriver-specific capabilities through ChromeOptions.
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--please-make-it-work"); // not a real switch
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
webDriver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
webDriver.get(url);
```

What I really need is to start the browser in "normal" mode. It doesn't need any profile settings, just the defaults that will open the PDF.

Comment: Have you checked this link ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29780399/how-to-open-pdf-in-chromedriver-2-15-without-downloading-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the recent change to the behaviour of the `--test-type` switch. It is [described in the ChromeDriver issue tracker](http://c.g.renhuali.cn/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1081).

The workaround is to disable this switch. Here's my code changed:

```java
// Add ChromeDriver-specific capabilities through ChromeOptions.
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Arrays.asList("test-type"));
webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
webDriver.get(url);
```

Comment: I can also confirm that Chrome dev version 44.0.2391.0 dev-m (64 bit) no longer has this issue, see answer in [How to open pdf in chromedriver 2.15 without downloading it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29780399/how-to-open-pdf-in-chromedriver-2-15-without-downloading-it/30074263#30074263)